# why the notification doesn't show if I send using data message through firebase cloud function?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I send FCM using cloud function like this

```
const payload = {
      data: {
         imagePath: imagePath,
         priority: priority,
         title: title,
         body: body
      }
 }

 await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,payload)
```

here is the code on my Android app, in `onMessageReceived`, this `onMessageReceived` code below is actually getting called, but I don't know why the notification doesn't show in my device

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

        var title: String = ""
        var body: String = ""
        var priority: String = ""
        var imagePath: String = ""


        remoteMessage.notification?.let {
            title = it.title ?: ""
            body = it.body ?: ""
        }


        val notificationData = remoteMessage.data
        priority = notificationData["priority"] ?: ""
        imagePath = notificationData["imagePath"] ?: ""
        title = notificationData["title"] ?: ""
        body = notificationData["body"] ?: ""

        setUpNotification(title,body,priority,imagePath)
    }
```

and to show notification to device

```
private fun setUpNotification(title: String, message: String, priority: String, imagePath: String) {


        val channel = if (priority == "high") NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_IMPORTANT else NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_MISCELLANEOUS

        var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .build()

        notificationManager.notify(1, notification)

    }
```

but if I add notification message (not just data message) on the payload like this

```
            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    body: body,
                    title: title,
                },

                data: {
                    imagePath: imagePath,
                    priority: priority,
                    title: title,
                    body: body
                }
            }
```

then the notification will show on my device

Comment: pass static random data in  `setUpNotification` method check this method is perfectly working or not .

Comment: @frankenstein yes it is also get called but I don't know why it doesnt show

Comment: problem is in your this method

Comment: @Alexa289 did you fix this?

Comment: @Black_Bacardi yup, in my case the problem is not in FCM at all, but in the way I create  a channel in Android. you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60105947/why-my-app-always-crash-when-creating-notification-manager

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private fun sendNotification(title: String, messageBody: String, notify_type: String) {
    var icon= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    val intent = Intent("SplashActivity")// use your activity 
    intent.putExtra("type", "notification")// here i'm passing data onClick of notification
    intent.putExtra("title", notify_type)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val r = Random()
    val i1 = r.nextInt(20 - 0 + 1) + 0
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,i1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    val channelId = this.resources.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_appicon)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, "Default channel",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    manager.notify(i1,builder.build())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options.html#notifications_and_data_messages) there are 2 types of messages: **Notification** messages and **Data** messages.

When you add the `Notification` part to your massage you are changing type of massage from Data type to Notification type. 
In the same documentation you can find that Notification type "automatically displays the message to end-user devices".

I think this mechanism is taking care of showing notification when you add `Notification` part. You can search for solution is your client app, as most probably the problem lies there.